Blazor, .NET 8 MapRazorComponents fallback
We are migrating Blazor Server application to .NET 8.
Previously, we've used a custom router in _Host.cshtml to resolve routes not defined via @page (convention-based routing, similar to MVC). In the new hosting model, with MapRazorComponents I can't find a way to do the same, but for a Razor component, in this case App. Is this possible or do we have to fall back to _Host.cshtml?

With .NET8, you can easilly add routing to the middleware with app.MapGet("/myRoute", x => {Action to do}). (or app.MapPost(...)) It depends of what you want to map behing your routes, you can also use app.MapControllers() or even app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode/{0}")

You could use Custom router component to achieve your requirement that will maps URLs to specific Razor components without altering the URL.
CustomRouter component will capture the url path and dynamically resolves and renders the appropriate Razor component based on custom logic.
CustomRouter.razor:
@page "/{*path}"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    private Type _componentType;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Resolve the component type based on the Path
        _componentType = ResolveComponent(Path);
    }

    private Type ResolveComponent(string path)
    {
        return path switch
        {
            "foo" => typeof(FooComponent),
            "bar" => typeof(BarComponent),
            _ => typeof(NotFoundComponent)
        };
    }
}

@if (_componentType != null)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type="_componentType" />
}
else
{
    <p>Component not found</p>
}

App.razor:
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <CustomRouter />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

Program.cs:
using BlazorCustomRouter;
using BlazorCustomRouter.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

This will work with .net 8 and it will also create  similar to MVC convention-based routing. If you prefer to keep the routing more declarative or need to more complex routing patterns, you might consider implementing middleware to handle some of the routing before it reaches Blazor.

The @page "/{*path}" trick is smart - I don't like the perf penalty this will incur (double route resolution) and I'm not sure how does .net core handle the pattern now with all the changes in routers they do now, I lost track of it.

@MatějŠtágl  Regarding your concern about the performance because of the double route you could use the custom routing middleware as alternative. that will check the incoming path and redirect it to the appropriate Razor component page before the request reaches the Blazor router. This can help you with the double route issue. By using {*path} route parameter captures the entire URL after the base path. While this is powerful, it can potentially match unintended routes, leading to more complex routing logic in ResolveComponent.

Could you please extend your answer to show a minimal example of how to redirect routes to Razor components via middleware?

right now facing some issue with the middleware but for a now you could go with this @page "/{*path}" solution

@MatějŠtágl let me know if you have any other concern

I don't want to go with the "/{*path}". As I said, I consider it a smart trick but not something I wnt to use. The question will stay marked as the answer, but if you'd like to put in the extra effort and include the middleware part, that's where the real value would be for me (as I haven't been able to research that on my own). Thanks.

@MatějŠtágl i will try to share the possible solution with the middleware soon

You can build custom routing as middleware, which handles the routing:
In Program.cs:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Check for custom routes
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/custom-route"))
    {
        // Handle custom routing logic
        context.Response.Redirect("/CustomComponent");
        return; // Skip the next middleware
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});


context.Response.Redirect changes the URL, no? I don't want that. Client goes to /foo, and stays on /foo.
